# Recuperar datos de varios checkbox al editar un formulario Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un formulario de edición que tiene muchos campos checkbox y necesito recuperarlos en la vista de edición,

view:

```
<div class="uk-container">

<div class="uk-margin uk-text-left" uk-grid>
    <legend class="uk-legend"><strong>4. Requerimientos de Calidad</strong></legend>
        <div class="uk-width-1-3"> 
        {!! Form::label('quality_control', '¿Realizar control de calidad?',['class' => '']) !!}
        {!! Form::select('quality_control',['' => 'Seleccione','Si' =>'Si','No' =>'No'],false,['class' => 'uk-select', 'required'])!!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="uk-flex" uk-grid>

    <div class="uk-text-left uk-width-1-3">
        <label>4.1. Pruebas sobre Propiedades Mecánicas</label><br>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'Resistencia a la Ruptura',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!} Resistencia a la Ruptura<br/>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'Resistencia al Impacto (Impacto al Dardo)',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!} Resistencia al Impacto (Impacto al Dardo)<br/>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'Coeficiente de Fricción',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!} Coeficiente de Fricción<br/>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'Coeficiente de Barrera',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!} Coeficiente de Barrera<br/>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'Prueba de Tracción',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!} Prueba de Tracción<br/>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'Prueba de Elongación',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!} Prueba de Elongación
    </div>

    <div class="uk-text-left uk-width-1-3">
        <label>4.2. Pruebas sobre Propiedades de Barrera</label><br>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'Permeabilidad al Vapor de Agua',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!} Permeabilidad al Vapor de Agua<br/>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'Permeabilidad al Oxigeno',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!} Permeabilidad al Oxigeno<br/>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'Permeabilidad a la transmisión de Luz',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!} Permeabilidad a la transmisión de Luz
    </div>

    <div class="uk-text-left uk-width-1-3">
        <label>4.3. Pruebas Microbiológicas</label><br/>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'Mesófilos',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!}  Mesófilos<br/>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'Coliferos',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!} Coliferos<br/>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'Mohos y Levaduras',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!} Mohos y Levaduras<br/>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'E-coli',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!} E-coli
    </div>

     <div class="uk-text-left uk-width-1-3">
        <label>4.3. Pruebas de Migración</label><br/>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'Global',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!}  Global<br/>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'Especifica',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!} Especifica<br/>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'Metales Pesados',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!} Metales Pesados
    </div>

    <div class="uk-margin uk-text-left uk-width-1-3">
        <label>4.4. Certificaciones</label><br/>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'BPM',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!}  BPM<br/>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'BASC',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!} BASC<br/>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'NTC',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!} NTC<br/>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'ISO',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!} ISO
    </div>

    <div class="uk-margin uk-text-left uk-width-1-3">
        <label>4.5. Niveles de Calidad Aceptables</label><br/>
        {!! Form::checkbox('protection[]', 'ACS/AQL',false,['class'=>'uk-checkbox check-disabled']) !!} ACS / AQL
    </div>

</div>
```

controlador:

```
public function edit($id){

    $datasheet = Datasheet::findOrFail($id);
    $structure = Structure::pluck('dsc_name_structure','id')->prepend('Seleccione', '')->toArray();
    return view('backend.profile.users.datasheet.edit')
    ->with('datasheet', $datasheet)
    ->with('structure', $structure);
}
```

Controlador: función store

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $datasheets = new Datasheet($request->all());       
    $datasheets->user_id = auth()->id();
    $datasheets->protection = $request->protection;
    $datasheets->protection = implode(',', $datasheets->protection);
    $datasheets->save();
    session()->flash('success', 'Ficha creada correctamente');
    return redirect()->route('datasheet.index'); 
}
```

Los checkbox que selecciono al crear el formulario me los separa por coma (,) al crear el registro en la BD ¿como podría recuperar esos datos y que se marquen en la posición respectiva donde los seleccione?

Gracias!!.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que estás usando [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html). En ese caso, simplemente tenés que tener un array con los valores de los checboxes en la propiedad `protection` (que es como se llaman los checkboxes).

**Opción 1:**
Como los tenés separados por comas, simplemente deberías hacer un explode.

```
public function edit ($id) {
    $datasheet = Datasheet::findOrFail($id);
    $datasheet->protection = explode(',', $datasheet->protection);
    $structure = Structure::pluck('dsc_name_structure','id')->prepend('Seleccione', '')->toArray();
    return view('backend.profile.users.datasheet.edit')
    ->with('datasheet', $datasheet)
    ->with('structure', $structure);
}
```

**Opción 2:**
Usar un [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor), pero según que uso le des tal vez esto te traiga problemas en otros lados.

Datasheet.php:

```
public function getProtectionAttribute($valor)
{
    return explode(',', $valor);
}
```

**Opción 3:**
En vez de guardar separando por comas, guarda como `JSON` y usá [Attribute Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting), donde definís que `protection` es un `array`. De esa forma, al guardar se convierte automáticamente en `JSON` y al obtener el valor se transforma automáticamente en un `array`.

Datasheet.php:

```
protected $casts = [
    'protection' => 'array',
];
```

Controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $datasheets = new Datasheet($request->all());       
    $datasheets->user_id = auth()->id();
    $datasheets->protection = $request->protection;
    $datasheets->save();
    session()->flash('success', 'Ficha creada correctamente');

    return redirect()->route('datasheet.index'); 
}
```